# How to send a request to the current page with $.get in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<form method="GET">
...
</form>
```

Like the default action of submiting a form?

Comment: have you tried $.get("/",.. etc);?

Comment: That won't work,it'll send request to the root.

Comment: @Baddie: that will get the root page, not the current page (i.e. stackoverflow.com, not stackoverflow/questions/1865......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try $.get(""); ?

Answer (score 2):

You could always pass `#` or `window.location.href` as URL...